# TableRow style class not sticking to row when ordering TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add/remove a style class to a table row based on a boolean in the row item.

Adding and removing the class works as expected with the following code. But when I click on the column header to reorder the table, the style sticks to the row id instead of the row item. Meaning if before ordering the first row was styled, after ordering the style is still on the first row instead of the row at the new position.

```
setRowFactory(table -> {
    TableRow<PowerPlantPM> row = new TableRow<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(PowerPlantPM pp, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(pp, empty);
            if (!empty && pp != null) {
                pp.savedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (newValue) {
                        getStyleClass().remove("unsaved");
                    } else {
                        getStyleClass().add("unsaved");
                    }
                });
                // the following binding works (including ordering), but is not what I want because of the ":selected" pseudo class
                // styleProperty().bind(Bindings.when(pp.savedProperty()).then("").otherwise("-fx-background-color: #f2dede"));
            }
        }
    };
    return row;
});
```

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve. How do I get the style to stick to the row item when reordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TableRow` is reused as much as possible, in your `updateItem` you need to query the corresponding property, not add a listener to it. The listener will only fire if the property changes, but the `TableRow` may asked to redraw on a different position, or a different item.

```
protected void updateItem(PowerPlantPM pp, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(pp, empty);
        if (!empty && pp != null) {
            if (!pp.isSaved()) {
                 getStyleClass().add("unsaved");
            } else {
                 getStyleClass().remove("unsaved");
            }
            .....
        }
 }
```

Create your `ObservableList` with the properties it should watch with

```
 ObservableListFX<PowerPlantPM> powerplants = 
   Collections.observableArrayList(pp -> new Observable[] { pp.savedProperty() });
```

This list will report changes on the items for the properties you returned in the `Observable[]`.

Comment: Great. Works perfectly. I used a combination of yours and @fabian's solution `if (!empty && pp != null) { pseudoClassStateChanged(RootPanel.UNSAVED, !pp.isSaved()); } else { pseudoClassStateChanged(RootPanel.UNSAVED, false); }`

Answer (score 1):

You never unregister the listener from the old items. Also the listener is not called for the initial value of the property. Even if it was, your code could result in the same style class being added multiple times to a node. Furthermore cells may become empty. You need to remove the style class in that case too.

To avoid adding the same style class multiple times use a pseudoclass:

```
final PseudoClass unsaved = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unsaved");

setRowFactory(table -> {
    TableRow<PowerPlantPM> row = new TableRow<>() {
        private final ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(unsaved, !newValue);
        };

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(PowerPlantPM pp, boolean empty) {
            PowerPlantPM oldItem = getItem();
            if (oldItem != null) {
                // remove old listener
                oldItem.savedProperty().removeListener(listener);
            }

            super.updateItem(pp, empty);
            if (empty || pp == null) {
                // remove pseudoclass from empty cell
                pseudoClassStateChanged(unsaved, false);
            } else {
                // add new listener & handle initial value
                pp.savedProperty().addListener(listener);
                pseudoClassStateChanged(unsaved, pp.isSaved());
            }
        }
    };
    return row;
});
```

(Of course you need to adjust your CSS selectors to use `:unsaved` instead of `.unsaved`.)

Comment: This is working perfectly. I used the accepted solution with your hint to pseudo classes.